# uploading a spreadsheet to sharepoint and making only few fields editable

Tags: sharepoint

I have sharepoint 2007 and have been trying to make few fields not editable after uploading to sharepoint. I have searched a lot in sharepoint and have not found a proper way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a requirement for Excel, not SharePoint. Try locking the cells before uploading the file to SharePoint. What you are asking for does not exist in SharePoint.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/freeze-or-lock-rows-and-columns-HP001217048.aspx
http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excel2007tips/qt/080428_lockcell.htm

Best Regards,

Ashley

Comment: Hi. I locked few feilds in the spreadsheet that i wanted to upload to sharepoint.After uploading to sharepoint I'm still able to edit the locked columns when i select edit in datasheet option. Is there a way i can retain the locked column functionality in datasheet option as well. Thanks

Comment: Hi, You are describing two different things. Spreadsheet can lock cells, columns and rows. SharePoint lists can prevent changed to rows through permissions but this is not advised for large lists due to performance issue when you have large lists. 
You are also describing what sounds like column permissions in lists which are available through third party products. I suggest you revert to some more basic user training before proceeding with questions at this level. Lists are not spreadsheets and spreadsheets are not lists.